# gsm call from pc via android phone

Tags: wi-fi, calls

Is there a way to call from Windows PC using android phone connected via WiFi?

I tried to use [Remote Phone Call](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=justPhone.remotePhoneTrial), but it's not so good you need be connected to phone via Bluetooth.